# DFS implementation

Tags: graph, go, depth-first-search

I implemented DFS using recursion in Go. When I dfs the graph, I am able to get the path of traversal. But I'm unsure what else could I add to this DFS in order to make the search better.

Also, Is there any benefit from using a stack instead of traditional recursion? I know that recursion uses stack as underlying data structure. I'm also setting the capacity of list for every vertex.

## dfs.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Vertex struct {
    visited    bool
    value      string
    neighbours []*Vertex
}

func (v *Vertex) connect(vertex *Vertex) {
    v.neighbours = append(v.neighbours, vertex)
}

type Graph struct{}

func (g *Graph) dfs(vertex *Vertex) {

    if vertex.visited != true {
        vertex.visited = true
        fmt.Println(vertex)
        if len(vertex.neighbours) != 0 {
            for _, v := range vertex.neighbours {
                g.dfs(v)
            }
        } else {
            return
        }
    }

}

func (g *Graph) disconnected(vertices ...*Vertex){
   for _, v := range vertices{
      g.dfs(v)
   }
}

func main() {
    v1 := Vertex{false, "A", make([]*Vertex, 0, 5)}
    v2 := Vertex{false, "B", make([]*Vertex, 0, 5)}
    v3 := Vertex{false, "C", make([]*Vertex, 0, 5)}
    v4 := Vertex{false, "D", make([]*Vertex, 0, 5)}
    v5 := Vertex{false, "E", make([]*Vertex, 0, 5)}
    g := Graph{}
    v1.connect(&v2)
    v2.connect(&v4)
    v2.connect(&v5)
    v3.connect(&v4)
    v3.connect(&v5)
    g.dfs(&v1)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a recursion is quite elegant here (to know about the performance, you would need to do some benchmarks).

Regarding your code, I would suggest some minor changes to make it more readable:

1. `if vertex.visited != true {` is the same as `if !vertex.visited {`
2. first handle specific cases with an early return and then the general case: this way augmented indentation concerns only the specific cases
3. you can iterate over an empty (or [even nil](https://play.golang.org/p/DzEKJsnZgUs)) slice
4. use unpacking
5. I don't think that initializing the slice capacity brings much

Code rewritten with this changes:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Vertex struct {
    visited    bool
    value      string
    neighbours []*Vertex
}

func NewVertex(value string) *Vertex {
    return &Vertex{
        value: value,

        // the two following lines can be deleted, because the will be initialized with their null value
        visited:    false,
        neighbours: nil, // comment 5.
    }
}

func (v *Vertex) connect(vertex ...*Vertex) { // see comment 4.
    v.neighbours = append(v.neighbours, vertex...)
}

type Graph struct{}

func (g *Graph) dfs(vertex *Vertex) {
    if vertex.visited { // see comment 1.
        return // see comment 2.
    }
    vertex.visited = true
    fmt.Println(vertex)
    for _, v := range vertex.neighbours { // see comment 3.
        g.dfs(v)
    }
}

func (g *Graph) disconnected(vertices ...*Vertex) {
    for _, v := range vertices {
        g.dfs(v)
    }
}

func main() {
    v1 := NewVertex("A")
    v2 := NewVertex("B")
    v3 := NewVertex("C")
    v4 := NewVertex("D")
    v5 := NewVertex("E")
    g := Graph{}
    v1.connect(v2)
    v2.connect(v4, v5) // see comment 4.
    v3.connect(v4, v5) // see comment 4.
    g.dfs(v1)
}
```

Comment: Better to change the line:
`fmt.Println(vertex)`
To:
`fmt.Println(vertex.value)`

Comment: This is copy and paste of the original code: I don't think that it matters much (it really depends on what you want to see as output)